# unit test to mock the requests library in python throws No module named mock

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Python version: 2.7.13

I have already installed mock using pip

I am trying to write a unit test for a function making external api call and returning a response.

**source code:**    (appl.py)

```
def getdetails(self, jsonData):

        try:

            ## server not successfully registered as a deployment client
            if self.__getClients(jsonData):                          
                response = requests.get(cfg['url'], verify=False, auth=(cfg['username'], cfg['password']))
```

**test code:**

```
import unittest
import mock
from mock import patch, MagicMock
import appl

 @patch('appl.requests.get')  # Mock 'requests' module 'get' method.
    def test_request_response_with_decorator(self, mock_get):
        data = { "a": 1, "b": 2 }

        """Mocking using a patcher"""
        mock_get_patcher = patch('appl.requests.get')
```

**Error:**

```
import mock
ImportError: No module named mock
```

Comment: It looks as though you may have installed `mock` in a different Python installation (or virtualenv) to the one you are using to run the test.